# Matplotlib contour plot not showing any contours

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, contour

The contour plot keeps coming out as just a dot on 0 but when I calculated the contours by hand, they were varied and substantial. Not sure whether there is something wrong with my code or my maths? :

```
Re = 6371000
rho = np.linspace(-20*Re, 20*Re, 2000)
z1 = np.linspace(-10*Re, 10*Re, 2000)
z = z1[:, np.newaxis]
Be = 3120*10**(-9)
F = (rho**2)*Be*(Re/np.sqrt(rho**2 + z**2))**3
plt.contour(rho, z1, F)
```

Comment: Note that the function has a pole inside your data range. So where would you expect to see the contours?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your help! I redid the code with meshgrids but it still did not work. I then tried setting the levels manually and the contours showed up so I think my Matplotlib settings don't automatically show contours.

Comment: No, the matplotlib settings are fine. As I said, you have a pole in your data. Hence all contours are around the pole.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry I think I've made myself a bit unclear- the problem was that there was just a single dot on zero, not that the contours are centered around the pole. Now there are several visible contours around the pole instead of an empty page with just a dot in the middle which is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I understood that. The reason is that **all** the contours are on the pole, so they appear as a single dot to you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Shouldn’t the contours be more visible though even with all of them on the page? I thought Matplotlib automatically sized it so the scale of the plot matched the range of values. Whereas in this case, they were all crammed into the centre of the page

Comment: Yes, that's what matplotlib does. A contour is a line along the solution of `z=f(x,y)` for a specific `z`. If no levels are specified, matplotlib automatically chooses ~8 or so contour levels, which are equally spaced between the minimum and maximum data. So in your case, almost the complete range of values is concentrated on the pole. Hence all contours are at a single position in  the x,y space.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh I see what you mean now, thanks